# Resonance of a system featuring a collection of individual resonators?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, frequency, resonance

Suppose you had a number of harmonic oscillators, each with different resonant frequencies in a system.

Does this imply that their is an overall system resonance that is dependent on the individual oscillators and their resonant frequencies? Ie. System resonance = $f_{res} = f(g_1, g_2, ..., g_n)$ where the $g_i$ represent the $n$ harmonic oscillators.

Or is the resonance of the system simply multiple resonances, that is, the resonant frequencies of all the individual oscillators? Ie. $f_{sys} = \{g_{1res}, g_{2res}, ..., g_{nres}\}$.

Or is it both? Or is it something else?

Comment: How are they coupled?  You appear to have fallen into a very nasty branch of structural engineering analysis, by the way.

Comment: Well when they oscillate they create pressure waves that hit each of the other oscillators which influences the pressure waves created by the other oscillators...which in turn influence....its a multiple scattering situation.

Comment: @Riggs as Carl Withoft stated you need more information regarding an assumption of the structure of the system. The question just poses a collection of independent resonators, but no assumptions of how they might interact with one another. A beat frequency can only exist if there is a media (structure) present that admits input frequencies from sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You typically have one position and one velocity variable per oscillator. The equation of motion of mass $i$ is $m_ix_i''=k_ix_i+$coupling terms. If the forces from the coupling terms are small, the frequencies do not change much. If the coupling is large, you will have as many modes as oscillators, but the frequencies can be anything. You wind up finding the eigenvalues of a matrix for the frequencies and the eigenvectors for the mode shapes.

A classic example is coupled pendulums.  You have two identical pendulums oscillating in the same plane at the same frequency.  Now connect a weak spring between them.  If you pull one pendulum out of vertical, it will start to swing.  After a short while, the other will start to swing as well.  After a longer while, the second is swinging and the first is not.  What is happening is you have introduced a coupling term $k(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ into the restoring force.  The normal modes are the two pendulums swinging in phase at the original frequency, as the spring does not stretch at all, and the two swinging exactly out of phase.  In the second case, the spring provides extra restoring force, so the frequency rises.  When you pull one pendulum, you excite both modes and you see the beat between them.